# How to add multiple properties in a Textblock programatically using WPF & c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

How do I add multiple properties, in this case `Foreground` & `FontSize` to a particular text in a textblock in WPF using c# code ?

I've tried doing it like below but getting error

```
mytxtblock.Inlines.Clear();
mytxtblock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Bills pending for Processing: ") { Foreground = Brushes.Aquamarine });
mytxtblock.Inlines.Add(new Run(pendingBills.ToString()) { Foreground = Brushes.LimeGreen } { FontSize = 13 });
```

Help !

Comment: and what error do you get?

Comment: you were right..syntax error. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one thing that is a syntax error

Instead of

```cs
mytxtblock.Inlines.Add(
  new Run(pendingBills.ToString()) 
  { 
    Foreground = Brushes.LimeGreen 
  } 
  { 
    FontSize = 13 
  });
```

you have to use

```cs
mytxtblock.Inlines.Add(
  new Run(pendingBills.ToString()) 
  { 
    Foreground = Brushes.LimeGreen, 
    FontSize = 13 
  });
```

Whenever you ask, you should also describe the error message itself. I do not know if that is a copy/paste error from you or the real problem you have.